# get integer values using regex

Tags: java, regex

StringBuilder values outputs following values.

```
StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder();

2020 May 12 09:28:11.292856 arrisxi6 runAppManager.sh[28161]: 200512-09:28:11.277875 [mod=RDKBROWSER2, lvl=INFO] [tid=28787] onConsoleLog:rdkbrowser.cpp:1130 [ConsoleAPI:473]: Progress: videoBufferedMiliseconds 2015
2020 May 12 09:28:12.282703 arrisxi6 runAppManager.sh[28161]: 200512-09:28:12.281919 [mod=RDKBROWSER2, lvl=INFO] [tid=28787] onConsoleLog:rdkbrowser.cpp:1130 [ConsoleAPI:473]: Progress: videoBufferedMiliseconds 12025
2020 May 12 09:28:13.280853 arrisxi6 runAppManager.sh[28161]: 200512-09:28:13.280054 [mod=RDKBROWSER2, lvl=INFO] [tid=28787] onConsoleLog:rdkbrowser.cpp:1130 [ConsoleAPI:473]: Progress: videoBufferedMiliseconds 15029
2020 May 12 09:28:14.280813 arrisxi6 runAppManager.sh[28161]: 200512-09:28:14.280181 [mod=RDKBROWSER2, lvl=INFO] [tid=28787] onConsoleLog:rdkbrowser.cpp:1130 [ConsoleAPI:473]: Progress: videoBufferedMiliseconds 14029
```

From the above values I need to get  values 2015, 12025, 15029, 14029 as list . It can be integer, long or double. Using regex How Can i get these values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try the below regex to achieve your purpose:

```
videoBufferedMiliseconds\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`videoBufferedMiliseconds\s+`** - Matches `videoBufferedMiliseconds` literally along with one or more white-space characters.
>
> **`(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`** - Represents a capturing group capturing integers, double or long.
>
> **`$`** - Represents end of the line.

[image: pictorial representation]

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/uUN12i/5)

**Sample Implementation in java:**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
public class Main
{
    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("videoBufferedMiliseconds\\s+(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String string = "2020 May 12 09:28:11.292856 arrisxi6 runAppManager.sh[28161]: 200512-09:28:11.277875 [mod=RDKBROWSER2, lvl=INFO] [tid=28787] onConsoleLog:rdkbrowser.cpp:1130 [ConsoleAPI:473]: Progress: videoBufferedMiliseconds 2015.234\n"
     + "2020 May 12 09:28:12.282703 arrisxi6 runAppManager.sh[28161]: 200512-09:28:12.281919 [mod=RDKBROWSER2, lvl=INFO] [tid=28787] onConsoleLog:rdkbrowser.cpp:1130 [ConsoleAPI:473]: Progress: videoBufferedMiliseconds 12025\n"
     + "2020 May 12 09:28:13.280853 arrisxi6 runAppManager.sh[28161]: 200512-09:28:13.280054 [mod=RDKBROWSER2, lvl=INFO] [tid=28787] onConsoleLog:rdkbrowser.cpp:1130 [ConsoleAPI:473]: Progress: videoBufferedMiliseconds 15029\n"
     + "2020 May 12 09:28:14.280813 arrisxi6 runAppManager.sh[28161]: 200512-09:28:14.280181 [mod=RDKBROWSER2, lvl=INFO] [tid=28787] onConsoleLog:rdkbrowser.cpp:1130 [ConsoleAPI:473]: Progress: videoBufferedMiliseconds 14029";
        
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

You can find the sample run of the above implementation in [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/B1Wu0gL68)

Answer (score 0):

You can use positive lookbehind assertion for this

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=videoBufferedMiliseconds)\\s*(\\d+.?\\d+)");
```

**Code:**

```
StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder();
values.append("2020 May 12 09:28:11.292856 arrisxi6 runAppManager.sh[28161]: 200512-09:28:11.277875 [mod=RDKBROWSER2, lvl=INFO] [tid=28787] onConsoleLog:rdkbrowser.cpp:1130 [ConsoleAPI:473]: Progress: videoBufferedMiliseconds 2015\n")
        .append("2020 May 12 09:28:12.282703 arrisxi6 runAppManager.sh[28161]: 200512-09:28:12.281919 [mod=RDKBROWSER2, lvl=INFO] [tid=28787] onConsoleLog:rdkbrowser.cpp:1130 [ConsoleAPI:473]: Progress: videoBufferedMiliseconds 12025\n")
        .append("2020 May 12 09:28:13.280853 arrisxi6 runAppManager.sh[28161]: 200512-09:28:13.280054 [mod=RDKBROWSER2, lvl=INFO] [tid=28787] onConsoleLog:rdkbrowser.cpp:1130 [ConsoleAPI:473]: Progress: videoBufferedMiliseconds 15029\n")
        .append("2020 May 12 09:28:14.280813 arrisxi6 runAppManager.sh[28161]: 200512-09:28:14.280181 [mod=RDKBROWSER2, lvl=INFO] [tid=28787] onConsoleLog:rdkbrowser.cpp:1130 [ConsoleAPI:473]: Progress: videoBufferedMiliseconds 14029.123\n");

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=videoBufferedMiliseconds)\\s*(\\d+.?\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(values);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

**Output:**

```
2015
12025
15029
14029.123
```

Comment: This answer is also good +1. Just will recommend adding the case for decimal values too. Your regex will not match for decimal values as mentioned in the requirement by the OP. Please check [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/uUN12i/4) Please edit and it will be fine.

Comment: oh yes, that's a good point! thanks:) updated the answer